# how to join tables without common column and based on a condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join multiple tables based on a certain condition. That is if locID is 1 then how can I get count of various departments that are in that location. The table structures are below.

Table 1: Area

```
id   userdeptID entityID
1      2           1
2      2           1
3      4           3
```

Table 2: Entity

```
id  locID
1    1
2    1
```

Table 3: userDept

```
id userID  deptID 
1   1      3
2   2      4
```

Expected output

```
count(deptID) locID
  2             1
```

As I am not sure how to implement such a query I do not have any sample query. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct then here is a sample. You can try this code:

```
Select count(u.deptID),E.locID
FROM Area A
LEFT JOIN Entity E on E.id=A.entityID
LEFT JOIN userDept u on u.userID =A.userdeptID  
where E.locID = 1
GROUP BY E.locID
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Ankit the query is working but is not giving the correct output.

Comment: @Jerry, please try it now, i have updated the code. Now it gives the correct output

Comment: For the details provided by you in the question, i am able to get the desired output...Please have a look at the screenshot, can you tell me what issue you are facing?

Comment: It's mostly something that I am missing here. Anyways thanks a lot it did help me a lot!!!!!